# Four boxes side-by-side with css

Tags: css

I want to make four equal boxes with 10 small (thumb) boxes in each. How can this be done with css? Here is the image of what is the goal.
[image]

So far I have the left column box

```
.left_column{
     margin-top: 10px;
     width: 150px;
     float: left;
     border:2px solid #ccc;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 10px;
     font-size: 14px;
     background-color: #f0f0f0;
     color: #888;
}
.left_column p {
     text-align: center;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
     font-size: 20px;
}
.left_column a {
     text-decoration: none;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
```

edit:
[Here is the Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc6zd5x8/2/)

Comment: Will you able to fiddle it out

Comment: Yes, just a sec I'll try to fiddle it.

Comment: Edited with feddle. @Liam, are you trying to offering your services or?

Comment: Search on SO, you can find similar example; and might be helpful.

Comment: @KheemaPandey, I finded some but my real problem are the small boxes inside the big.

Comment: For small boxess you may use `ul` and `li` . where you can put image or text and its easier to maintain. Also is much easier and more semantic .

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for? http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc6zd5x8/1/

Comment: Fiddle is updated in the question. I think I've made the big boxes. Now the small one.

Comment: @ctwheels, I've updated my fiddle in the question. There I have made the big boxes.

Comment: Like this then? http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc6zd5x8/3/

Comment: Yes, exactly like this. It's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: If you're wondering I simply added a div with the class "littlebox" inside your div with the class "div" and added the following code to css: `.littlebox{
    width:75px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}`

Comment: Yes, I saw it. It's really simple but working. Just one more thing is it possible `height` of the small boxes to be auto according to the height of the thumb? If I put `height: auto;`?

Comment: I assume the boxes are all images?

Comment: Yes, they are but some are 50px other are 100.. most of them they are 75x75 .. but some are different size

Comment: Here, I've surrounded every 5 pictures in a table. You can change the code and add a class to be referenced instead of the table elements being referenced directly (suggested). I changed your .box elements to min-width instead of width and added the css table section at the bottom. The reason for changing the width to min-width is so that the .box divs will resize depending on content (if you have multiple 100x100 images that would cause them to overflow the container). Adding a new table each 5 images allows each table to follow a different td size: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sc6zd5x8/4/

Comment: You can post it like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a container for each of the boxes with a fixed width and then put the thumbnails inside. If you use float: left; on the container boxes then they will move depending on the window size.

Answer (score 0):

I can just suggest to use flex box.

It has only support for newer browsers but its actually totally easy to use and its responsive. Here is a small explanation:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The inner content could be simple created then by `float:left;` and `display: inline-block;`
Here is an example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fpuwk7dL/